# Suspicious Windows Update

Tags: drivers, windows-update, windows-server-2003

I have a computer running Windows Server 2003 x86 which is offering a suspicious Windows Update.

The title of the update is `Microsoft Corporation - Other Hardware - Microsoft UAA Bus Driver for High Definition Audio`.

The description is (Exact copy-paste; it doesn't have any links)

```
Size: 77 KB

microsoft system software update released on March 05 2004.
```

In Device Manager, I have such a device listed under System Devices, and it's working properly.  If I click Update Drivers, it starts downloading a driver from Windows Update (which I cancelled)

Does anyone know what this is, and why it's so different from normal updates? (No link, no capitalization in Details)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**In case of doubt, don't do it.** You did well.

Then you should check the KB article code that is attached to the Update item description text. If you aren't presented a direct link to that article on the web:

- Open up Microsoft Knowledge Base
  (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/)
  and you are presented with the
  Microsoft search page with "kb"
  already input for you.
- You only need to paste the actual
  article number.

In your case, I suspect it is 888111. Confirm if that is the case. In any case, read the KB article and if that satisfies you, you can proceed with the update.

But if there is no KB article code reference anywhere in your Windows Update page:

- Microsoft screwed up for this
  particular update and forgot to link
  it to the appropriate KB article. I
  doubt it.
- You are being the victim of phishing.
  Confirm the Windows Update address on
  the you browser is really from
  Microsoft domain. Most likely it is,
  so no worries.
- There's something wrong with your
  driver and it is reporting a bad
  version number or somehow became
  corrupted or infected. You are then
  being presented an old update
  version.

The last is the most likely and I'd suggest uninstalling this device and reinstalling it.

Comment: The update has no link or KB number.  I'm seeing this in the built-in Automatic Updates window (from the systray icon), so there's no URL to check.  It sounds like 888111, but the KB page explicitly says it's not compatible with SP1 or higher; I have SP2.

Comment: Reinstall your device driver. This is a wrong windows update report probably reported because of a corrupt driver.

Answer (score 2):

I just searched for this update using WSUS. It is indeed a genuine Microsoft update and you can install it without worry.

You don't know me, of course, but if you have access to a server running Windows Server Update Services 3.0 you can verify this yourself by clicking **Search** (in the Actions pane), typing "UAA", and clicking **Find Now**.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any need for an audio device on this computer? If it's just running as a server and doesn't use audio in any way, you could always just disable the device in Device Manager. No device, no weird Windows Update request.

Otherwise, I would try [A Dwarf's suggestion](https://superuser.com/questions/56236/suspicious-windows-update/56252#56252) and uninstall/reinstall the original driver (or check the hardware company's website for the latest not-from-Microsoft-Update version.